# Failing to connect/get results from database using PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection, web-deployment

I am trying to connect to the database and display the information on the page.

Here is the model

```
<?php
// model for the totals of the wreath orders
require_once("dbconnect.php");

// connect to database and check errors
@ $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$connection_error = $dbc->connect_error;
if ($connection_error != null) {
  echo "<p>Error connectiong to database: $connection_error</p>";
  exit();
}
?>
```

Here is the code from the page where I construct the string and try to connect and display the data on the screen.

```
<?php
require_once('model.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE";

if  (isset ($_POST['fname'])) {
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $query = $query . " fname = '" . $fname . "' AND";
}
if (isset ($_POST['lname'])) {
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $query = $query . " lname = '" . $lname . "' AND";
}

if (isset ($_POST['age'])) {
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $query = $query . " age = '" . $age . "' AND";
}

if (isset ($_POST['city'])) {
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $query = $query . " city = '" . $city . "' AND";
}

$query = rtrim($query, " AND");
include('header.php');
?>
<div id="header">
<h1><strong>This is the information you requested</h1></strong>
</div>
<div id="main">
<?php
$results = $dbc->query($query);
$row_count = $result->num_rows;

for ($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++) :
        $product = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo $product['fname'] . " | " . $product['lname'] . " | " . $product['age'] . " | " . $product['city'] . ' <br />';
endfor;
?>
</div>
<?php
include('footer.php');
```

Here is the error I get

```
Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\testwebpage\Model\getinformation.php on line 34

Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\testwebpage\Model\getinformation.php on line 34
```

I can say I'm pretty new to this and am just not sure what would be wrong with the code.

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities. Enjoy having your server pwn3d. And as a general tip: if your code is having problems, do yourself a favor and STOP using the `@` error suppression error. PHP could be trying to tell you what's wrong, but you're stuffing you fingers in your ears and going "lalalalalalal can't hear you".

Comment: This is a text page on WAMP.  It will not be going live and I will be the only one using it.  The only person who would inject SQL into it would be me and I really don't think I would be doing that to myself.  As for the @ error suppression I have no idea what that means, can you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a different variable name. It should be `$results` instead of `$result`.

Replace them with:

```
$row_count = $results->num_rows; //line 34

$product = $results->fetch_assoc(); //line 37
```

That should fix the errors.

Comment: Thank you very much that fixed the problem! If I could give a thumbs up I would ;)